# Make button required before submit

Tags: jquery, html

i wanna ask this. so i have a form with gmaps geolocation.

[image]

the button on maps should be clicked, so the point is button should be required, right ?

required doesn't work with button guys. any idea ?

Comment: Share us your code or part of it to see what can be wrong

Comment: @iArcadia There is nothing wrong. The question is how he can make a Button on a form 'Required'. You can't. Buttons on a form initiate an action (Like Submit or Cancel) You can't assign a button to be a Form field of some kind.  So as I stated in my answer below.. you should fill a new field with the selected value from your Google Maps result and make that new field Required.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Don H I posted my comment in order for the question to be clearer (in my opinion). But I agree with you on the fact that a `<button>` cannot be required inside a form. However I would add a required radio input (or a checkbox) inside the button to resolve his question.

Answer (score -1):

Add a new form field: Location.
Clicking the button in the gmaps should (clientside) fill the 'Location' form field.
You can now 'Require' the Location field.

Tip: Make the Location field 'Disabled' so users can't put any values in directly.
This way they are forced to click the gmaps thing.